# Excel changes conditional formatting automatically

Tags: excel, ms-office

I created a large Excel template with lots of VBA Code and several worksheets. It also uses around 20 conditional formatting rules in one of the worksheets. Everything runs fine except of one problem.

The problem is: Excel changes the formatting of one of my rules when I close the workbook and open it again.

My rule looks like this:

```
=$G9="EUR" --> applied to: =$J$9:$BS$84, 
formatting: _-* #.##0,00 €_-;-* #.##0,00 €_-;_-* "-"?? €_-;_-@_-
```

(accounting preset with 2 decimal places)

And it changes it to this format when I close the workbook:

```
_(€* #.##0,00_);_(€* (#.##0,00);_(€* "-"??_);_(@_)
```

The worst of this: the second format displays negative numbers with braces around them, and I really don't like that.

Does someone know what could cause that?

Comment: i don't see it happening on my excel 2016, which version do you use

Comment: It's Excel 2013. My company didn't update yet :/